# cannot import name 'parse_version' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am having serious problems with sklearn. In particular, when doing:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-a35af2a4e137> in <module>
----> 1 from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py in <module>
     78     from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     79     from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 80     from .base import clone
     81     from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     82 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py in <module>
     19 from . import __version__
     20 from ._config import get_config
---> 21 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     22 from .utils.validation import check_X_y
     23 from .utils.validation import check_array

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py in <module>
     21 
     22 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
---> 23 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight
     24 from . import _joblib
     25 from ..exceptions import DataConversionWarning

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/class_weight.py in <module>
      5 import numpy as np
      6 
----> 7 from .validation import _deprecate_positional_args
      8 
      9 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in <module>
     23 from contextlib import suppress
     24 
---> 25 from .fixes import _object_dtype_isnan, parse_version
     26 from .. import get_config as _get_config
     27 from ..exceptions import NonBLASDotWarning, PositiveSpectrumWarning

ImportError: cannot import name 'parse_version' from 'sklearn.utils.fixes' (/Users/federiconutarelli/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/fixes.py)
```

which I am not able to fix since in fixes.py I can see

```
def _parse_version(version_string):
    version = []
    for x in version_string.split('.'):
        try:
            version.append(int(x))
        except ValueError:
            # x may be of the form dev-1ea1592
            version.append(x)
    return tuple(version)
```

which seem to me the same as parse_version. Why Is this error occurring? Can anyone please help me?

Thank you all,

Federico

Comment: Are you using the latest version of scikit-learn? I can't replicate your error with version 0.23.2 on Windows.

Comment: @MattDMo actually yeas. It also does not work when I simply make `import sklearn`. I pip uninstalled sklearn and the sudo pip installed it again. Maybe is the sudo part that does not work?...not sure

Comment: You need to start with `pip install -U sklearn` in the env you import from

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov thank you. I had tried it but after saying: Requirement already up-to-date:.. I call back import sklearn and the same error occurs. I am working on Jupiter notebook. So the steps  followed are: 1) `!pip install -U sklearn` 2) import sklearn. But the same error appears

Comment: If it can be useful, when I run from terminal I end up with `configparser.ParsingError: Source contains parsing errors: 'setup.cfg'
 [line 49]: '<<<<<<< HEAD\n'
 [line 50]: '=======\n'
 [line 51]: '    graphviz\n'
 [line 53]: "    matplotlib; python_version > '3.5'\n"
 [line 54]: '    pandas\n'
 [line 55]: '>>>>>>> 3606b0bcc7779b78e6df8991dbcd7b72ac3046ef\n' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my situation, I uninstall the two packages `scipy` and `scikit-learn` and then installed them. And then it works well. I try both `conda install` and `pip install` for many times, so I can't tell which way to install is better.

In the detailed error report, there should be some lines relevant to `scipy`. So I think this is an error about the incompatibility between these two packages and therefore some dll doesn't work well.

Answer (score 2):

You may resolve this by creating a fresh conda environment. Sometimes some conflicts prevent packages from running correctly.

Comment: I read a previous conversation on the topic which suggested the creation of a new condo env. I already tried it but I have to basically copy-paste my previous env otherwise some of the packages do not work...